DSolve/NDSolve two simple beam DE, left/right far pin end/connection joint continuity-error NDSolve called with two arguments; thre+ argument expected
I was able to get code for a single simply supported uniform loaded beam DE working fine.  Now I tried to expand to 2 connected uniform loaded beams, no solution is reached. I attempted to define BC for both beam sections and the continuity where the beams are attached.  IT looks OK to me.  I am just looking for plotted solutions now, not algebraic solutions.
error - NDSolve called with 2 arguments; 3 or more arguments are expected
Any input would be appreciated -
(*Define parameters*)
ClearAll;
EInew = 30000000; (*Example value for the bending stiffness*)
q = 10; (*Example value for the distributed load*)

L1 = 6000;
L2 = 4000;
L = L1 + L2;

x1Start = 0;  (*START POSITON OF BEAM 1*)
x2Start = 
  x1End = 50; (*END POSITON OF BEAM 1, (START POSITON OF BEAM 2*)
x2End = 100; (*END POSITON OF BEAM 2 *)

(*x1Start=0;
x1End=50;
x2Start=0;
x2End=50;*)

(*Define DEs for beam sections*)
DE1 = {EInew*y1''''[x1] == q};
DE2 = {EInew*y2''''[x2] == q};

(*Define initial conditions for each beam section  ORIGINAL *)
(*initialConditions1={y1[0]==0,y1'[0]==0,y1''[0]==0,y1'''[0]==0};
initialConditions2={y2[0]==0,y2'[0]==0,y2''[0]==0,y2'''[0]==0};*)

(*simple support both ends *)
(*initialConditions1={y1[x1Start]==0,y1''[x1End]==0,y1[x1End]==0,y1''[\
x1Start]==0 };
initialConditions2={y2[x2Start]==0,y2''[x2End]==0,y2[x2End]==0,y2''[\
x2Start]==0 };*)


initialConditions1 = {y1[x1Start] == 0, 
   y1''[x1Start] == 
    0 }; (* at far left end of beam 1 - is pin support - deflection & \
moment =0 *)
initialConditions2 = {y2[x2End] == 0, 
   y2''[x2End] == 
    0 };          (* at far right end of beam 2 - is pin support - \
deflection & moment =0 *)


(*initialConditions2={y2[x2Start]==0,y2''[x2End]==0};*)
(*sol=DSolve[{DE==0,y[0]==0, y[L]==0,y''[0]==0,y''[L]==0},y[X1],X1];  \
 *)

(*Define continuity conditions at beam 1 and beam 2 connection point*)
continuityConditions = {
   y1[x1End] == y2[x2Start],(*Displacement continuity*)
   y1'[x1End] == y2'[x2Start],(*Slope continuity*)
   y1''[x1End] == y2''[x2Start],(*Shear continuity*)
   y1'''[x1End] == y2'''[x2Start], (*Moment continuity*)
   y1''''[x1End] == y2'''[x2Start] 
   };

(*Solve the system of DEs*)
sol = NDSolve[
  {DE1, DE2, initialConditions1, initialConditions2, 
   continuityConditions},
  {y1[x1], {x1, x1Start, x1End},

   (*Define the domain for beam section 1*)
   y2[x2], {x2, x2Start, x2End}}
  ]

(*sol=DSolve[
{DE1,DE2,initialConditions1,initialConditions2,continuityConditions},
{y1[x1],{x1},
(*Define the domain for beam section 1*)
y2[x2],{x2}}
]*)



(*sol=DSolve[{DE==0,y[0]==0, y[L]==0,y''[0]==0,y''[L]==0},y[X1],X1]; *)  


    y1 = y1[x1] /. sol[[1]]
    y2 = y2[x2] /. sol[[2]]
    
    
    Plot[y1, {x1, x1Start, x1End}]
    Plot[y2, {x2, x2Start, x2End}]

